# Overload deferred procedure with non-polymorphic procedure in Fortran 2008

Tags: fortran, fortran2008

Is it possible to overload a deferred procedure with a non-polymorphic procedure?

I'd like to create an abstract class (`Parent`) with a procedure (`foo`) which must be overloaded by every class which extends `Parent`. I run into problems when I want to extend again, such that a class (`Grandchild`) extends a class (`Child`) which extends `Parent`.

Since Child is not abstract, its foo (`foo_Child`) must be polymorphic. But then `Grandchild` inherits `foo_Child`, rather than being forced to define `foo_Grandchild`. Further, since I don't want `foo_Child` to be polymorphic I want to be able to use `Child`-specific non-polymorphic functions within `foo_Child`.

```
module test_module

  type, abstract :: Parent
  contains
    procedure(foo_Parent), deferred :: foo
  end type

  abstract interface
    subroutine foo_Parent(this,input)
      import Parent
      class(Parent), intent(out) :: this
      character(*),  intent(in)  :: input
    end subroutine
  end interface

  type, extends(Parent) :: Child
  contains
    procedure :: foo => foo_Child
  end type

  type, extends(Child) :: Grandchild
    ! Is not required to define foo=>foo_Grandchild.
    ! This is not the behaviour I want.
  end type

  interface Child
    module procedure new_Child
  end interface
contains

function new_Child(input) result(this)
  character(*), intent(in) :: input
  type(Child)              :: this
end function

subroutine foo_Child(this,input)
  type(Child),  intent(out) :: this ! Fails: 'this' is not polymorphic.
  character(*), intent(in)  :: input

  this = Child(input) ! Fails if type(Child) is replaced by class(Child).
end subroutine
end module

program test
  use test_module
end program
```

To summarise:

Is there any way of making `foo_Child` be non-polymorphic but also overload `foo_Parent`? Or is there a way of calling non-polymorphic functions (at least `Child=Child` assignment with non-polymorphic rhs) in a polymorphic procedure? If not, is there a workaround?

(I don't want to define `class(Child)=type(Child)`, but will if it's the only option).

Comment: What did the compiler tell you? You can only overload type-bound procedures with procedures with a conforming arguments and every passed dummy argument must be polymorphic.

Comment: Yes, that. But if I change `type(Child)` to `class(Child)` to avoid the error, I can no longer use `this=Child(input)`, and `Grandchild` inherits `foo_Child`, which is not behaviour I want.

Comment: Polymorphic is not a term that applies to procedures and types in Fortran - it applies only to variables.  I think I know what you mean, but not necessarily what you need.

Comment: Ah, sorry, by "polymorphic procedure" I mean a procedure that takes `class(...) :: this` rather than `type(...) :: this`. I guess I'm using "polymorphic procedure" as shorthand for "procedure with polymorphic argument".

Comment: As to what I need: I'm writing an I/O handler. The `object%foo(input)` procedure is "convert the string `input` into `object`". Then anything which extends `Parent` can be read from a string. In `Parent`'s module, there is a bunch of file handling and such, with a bunch of functions which take `class(Parent) :: this` as arguments. I need some way of ensuring that every class which extends `Parent` has a procedure, `foo`, which can be called from the `Parent` module.

Comment: There are multiple questions here.  The simple answer to the opening sentence is "No", but what you really want to know is how to code something that addresses your requirements, of which we only have a glimpse.

Comment: Okay, I think I have a partial solution: by using `select type(this); type is(Child)` I can then treat `this` as non-polymorphic. It doesn't solve the issue of Grandchild inheriting `foo_Child`, and feels like a hack, but it works for now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dummy argument that corresponds to the passed object of a procedure binding must always be polymorphic.

The rules of the language for intrinsic assignment do not permit assignment to a non-allocatable polymorphic object.  This is because typically such an assignment would be an error akin to slicing - you would undefine the bits of the object that are declared in the dynamic type of the rhs but not in the declared type of the lhs.

A polymorphic object can be downcast to a non-polymorphic object using SELECT TYPE and a type guard that matches the dynamic type of the object.  You can also merrily slice to your hearts content via argument association - a polymorphic actual argument can be associated with a non-polymorphic dummy of the same declared type.

Extensions can be forced to implement a binding by making the parent type abstract and making (or leaving) the binding deferred (as you have already done).  In your situation that perhaps requires an additional type in your hierarchy.

```
Parent (abstract) --> Child (abstract) +-> RealChild (concrete)
                                       |-> GrandChild (concrete)
```

`Child` in the above might simply leave the foo binding deferred, or it may provide a procedure for that binding and then introduce a new deferred binding that `RealChild` and `GrandChild` need to implement.